# How to make scrollbar visible whenever a ScrollViewer is used?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm specifying that the `ScrollViewer` should have a visible scrollbar as follows:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
```

however, it's only visible when I'm actively scrolling. Otherwise it's invisible. I need it to be visible all the time or the user can't see that there's more information available.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try editing your `ScrollViewer` template in order to display the `ScrollBar` always?
Maybe this could be helpful!

[ScrollViewer: always show vertical scrollbar](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4295dfe0-9092-42a9-be7c-54942bfb975f/scrollviewer-always-show-vertical-scrollbar)